# Changing class instance variable from different class

Tags: ruby

I'm currently writing a command-line Tic Tac Toe game in Ruby, and I'm having issues changing a cell on the game board to the player's marker ("X" or "O").  In my code, I'm accessing the `cells` class variable in the `GameBoard` class through my `make_move` method in the `Player` class instance.  However, when I run the code, the cell does not change.

Code:

```
class GameBoard

    attr_accessor :cells

    def initialize 
        @@cells = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        display_board
    end

    def self.cells 
        @@cells
    end

    def display_board
        @@cells[0..2].each{|n| print n.to_s + " | "}
        print "\n-----------\n"
        @@cells[3..5].each{|n| print n.to_s + " | "}
        print "\n-----------\n"
        @@cells[6..8].each{|n| print n.to_s + " | "}
    end

end

class Player
    def initialize marker
        @marker = marker
    end

    def make_move number
        GameBoard.cells[number - 1] = @marker.to_s
    end
end 

def play_game
    puts "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!"
    GameBoard.new
end

play_game
bob = Player.new("X")
bob.make_move(1)
```

Should display:

```
             X | 2 | 3
            -----------
             4 | 5 | 6
            -----------
             7 | 8 | 9
```

Comment: Note: `@@` is a *class instance variable* that is *shared among all instances of a class*. You probably want `@` as a regular instance variable.

Comment: @tadman `@@` is a "class variable" (without "instance").

Comment: Furthermore, while it's possible to initialize an `@@` variable inside a method, it isn't good practice to do so. Instance variables are `@` variables that are initialized inside a method of the class (typically the `initialize` method), and you should only initialize instance variables inside a class method. Any other variables should be initialized at the top of the class itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This required some refactoring to make it more idiomatic Ruby, but the result is here:

```
class GameBoard
  attr_accessor :cells

  def initialize 
    # Use an instance variable that's local to this particular instance
    @cells = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  end

  # Define a method that represents this as a string. Note that it's not 
  # printed, meaning the caller can decide how to use this data.
  def to_s
    # Use each_slice to pull out rows of 3 and use join to glue them together
    # in the right layout.
    @cells.each_slice(3).map do |row|
      # Each row is converted from [1,2,3] to "1 | 2 | 3"
      row.join(' | ')
    end.join("\n" + "-" * 10 + "\n")
  end
end

class Player
  # Players are attached to particular boards with a marker
  def initialize marker, board
    @marker = marker
    @board = board
  end

  def make_move number
    @board.cells[number - 1] = @marker.to_s
  end
end
```

Then the main section of the code now looks like this:

```
puts "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!"
board = GameBoard.new

bob = Player.new("X", board)
bob.make_move(1)

# Here the .to_s method is called automatically by puts
puts board
```

Comment: Wow, this is an incredibly well written and complete answer.  Thank you!

Comment: When implementing `to_s`, Ruby gives you `board.display` for free.